# Facebook and gender identity

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When looking up gender identity on my Merriam Webster dictionary I was able to find the following quote:

> Facebook provides more than 50 options beyond "male" and "female" for users to describe their gender identity, from "gender questioning" and "neither" to "androgynous." —The Chicago Tribune

So, I would like to know, how do I navigate the Facebook web application so that I can find these fifty or more options, perhaps alongside with explanations of what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/276177272409629):

> To edit your basic personal info (example: gender, contact info, relationships, work, education):
>
> 1. Go to your profile.
> 2. Click **About** at the bottom of your cover photo.
> 3. In the left column, click the section you'd like to change.
> 4. Hover over the information you'd like to edit.
> 5. To the right of that section, click **Edit** or **Options**, then select **Edit**.
> 6. Use the [audience selector](https://www.facebook.com/help/120939471321735?helpref=faq_content) to choose who can see this information, then click Save Changes.
>
> If you set your gender to **Custom** and select one or more genders, you can also select an audience for your custom gender. In addition to your custom gender, you'll choose a **Pronoun**. The pronoun you select is [public](https://www.facebook.com/help/203805466323736?helpref=faq_content).

If you are not seeing custom gender option that means this option is not enabled in your country.